# Vungle 3.013 Duplicate Symbol Error,iPad Only, Xcode 6.2

Tags: ios, ipad, duplicate-symbol, vungle-ads

I integrated Vungle Video ads framework in my project(Universal), works fine with the iPhone, but when I try to run the same Project in iPad it fails at compilation throwing following logs

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is due to you not being on the latest version of XCode: 
"Our newest iOS SDK (3.0.13) was released in support of the newest version of XCode (6.3). Please verify you are using XCode 6.3 or higher to ensure a smooth integration.

If you are still using a version older than XCode 6.3, head over to the Appstore for a quick update to make sure you start serving Vungle ads in no time."

https://support.vungle.com/hc/en-us/articles/204451204-Vungle-s-iOS-SDK-3-0-13-and-XCode-6-3

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

I have answered a similar question [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31232396/1849539). please check it out.

I short what the problem might be that you are probably having multiple Vungle SDKs inside your project and so it is throwing duplicate symbols error. It might be possible that the error is due to another linker warning e.g.

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F"/Users/user/Desktop/qwer/../../Documents/Unity Projects/Unity 5.0.0 projects/MyGame/Assets/Editor/Vungle/VungleSDK"'
```

View the above mentioned link for further details.